# How to display 'wait' icon in activity title on android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-titlebar

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)
```

doesn't work for me, since it should be called before `onCreate` in the Activity, when I need to show it only when user pressed button in this Activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. You do want to use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

The trick is to toggle the display of the spinner via:

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean);
```

Pass `true` to show, `false` to hide. So in your Activity init or UI init then call it with false to hide it, then call it again with true to show it when your button click is fired.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about these methods.

Comment: Thanks! Can it be called from ASyncTask?

Comment: And, strange - but it doesn't work for me... Should it work on HTC?

Comment: Ahh, I should call `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean);` in onPreExecute/onPostExecute of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can still set the progress bar's visibility via [PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_OFF) and PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON after you've called `setContentView`.

You *can* in fact set FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS in `onCreate`, it just needs to be before `setContentView` is called.